# Obtain X.509 Certificate Fingerprint from Certificate Info

Tags: certificates, rsa, x.509

I would like to obtain the SHA1/MD5 fingerprint of an X.509 certificate in order to compare it with the one presented by a server before connecting. However, I currently don't have access to the certificate itself, the only info I have is the output of the `openssl x509 -text -noout -in cert.crt` command that I was provided (Serial number, Public Key, Exponent, ...). Is it possible to calculate the certificate fingerprint using that information?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**No**
I'd say no. Not in any practical way.

You'd have to have a parser to turn it back into a DER encoded ASN.1 data structure. This would give you the original certificate.

Two difficulties:
1. **No parser.** You probably don't have a parser to do this.
2. **You'll miss ASN.1 details.** Even if you did have a parser, not all information might be exposed to you.

Details are as follows:
**Type information in ASN.1**
Using ASN.1, the same information can be encoded in different ways. (For example: the "Common Name" field might be encoded as UTF-8 or something more like ASCII. And there is a tag field that says what the encoding is. So even if the encoded data looks exactly the same, it might be encoded in a different way. And this will totally change the hash value.)

**Nesting in ASN.1**
Also, there are different ways to nest things that wind up meaning the same thing. And I don't think "-noout -text" exposes these intricacies to you.

**ASN1PARSE printout might save you**
If you really, really want to know the innards of cert, you need OpenSSLs "[asn1parse](https://www.openssl.org/docs/apps/asn1parse.html)". (So if you had an asn1parse printout, then you could (in principle) parse this back into binary bit-perfectly.)